# Formulário para um model diferente

Tags: php, cakephp

Estou utilizando CakePHP 2.6.4.

Tenho duas tabelas no banco de dados: `despesas` e `receitas`. Tenho os métodos de CRUD da despesas e da receitas. Criei o *controller* `RelatoriosController` para relatórios detalhados das despesas e das receitas, mas quero reaproveitar as validações no *model* `Despesa` e `Receita`, além dos *callbacks* (`afterFind`, `beforeFind`, etc).

Como faço isso?

O meu controle `Despesas` é o seguinte:

**DespesasController**

```
<?php
public

function inserirDespesa()
{
 if ($this->request->isPost())
 {
  if ($this->Despesa->save($this->request->data))
  {
   $this->Session->setFlash("Despesa inserida");
   $this->redirect(array(
    'action' => 'inserirDespesa'
   ));
  }
  else
  {
   $this->Session->setFlash("Despesa não inserida");
  }
 }
}

public

function consultarDespesa()
{
 if ($this->request->is("post"))
 {
  $despesas = $this->Despesa->afterFind($this->Despesa->query("select despesas.id_despesa, despesas.despesa, despesas.valor_despesa, despesas.data_despesa, despesas.local_despesa, tipos.tipo from despesas inner join tipos on despesas.fk_id_tipo=tipos.id_tipo where year(data_despesa)='{$this->request->data['Despesa']['ano']}' and month(data_despesa)='{$this->request->data['Despesa']['mes']}'"));
  if ($despesas == null)
  {
   $this->Session->setFlash("Sua pesquisa não retornou nenhum resultado.");
  }
  else
  {
   $totalReceitas = $this->somarReceitasParaLiquido($this->request->data);
   $this->exibirDespesas($despesas, $totalReceitas);
  }
 }
}
```

**Modal Despesa:**

```
<?php
class Despesa extends AppModel

{
 public $name = 'Despesa';

 public $useTable = 'despesas';

 public $primaryKey = 'id_despesa';

 public $validate = array(

  'despesa' => array(
   'rule' => array(
    'notEmpty',
    'message' => 'O campo despesa deve ser informado'
   )
  )
 );
 public

 function beforeSave($options = Array())
 {
  $this->data['Despesa']['valor_despesa'] = $this->valor($this->data['Despesa']['valor_despesa']);
  $this->data['Despesa']['data_despesa'] = $this->converterDataParaEN($this->data['Despesa']['data_despesa']);
  return true;
 }

 public

 function afterFind($despesas, $primary = false)
 {
  foreach($despesas as $despesa => $campo)
  {
   $despesas[$despesa]['Despesa']['valor_despesa'] = $this->valor($campo['Despesa']['valor_despesa']);
   $despesas[$despesa]['Despesa']['data_despesa'] = $this->converterDataParaPT($campo['Despesa']['data_despesa']);
  }

  return $despesas;
 }
}

?>
```

**formulário de inserção:**

```
<?php  
echo $this->Form->create('Despesa');  

echo $this->Form->input('despesa', array('label'=>'* Despesa:', 'maxlength'=>'30'));  

//campo valor_despesa do tipo texto para aceitar a "," (vírgula).  
echo $this->Form->input('valor_despesa', array('label'=>'* Valor (apenas nÃºmeros, incluindo os centavos. Coloque 00 quando nÃ£o houver centavos):', 'maxlength'=>'10', 'type'=>'text', 'onkeypress'=>"mascara(this, valor)"));  

//data_despesa com type=text para possibilitar a digitação e o símbolo de "/".
echo $this->Form->input('data_despesa', array('label'=>'* Data:', 'type'=>'text', 'maxlength'=>'10', 'onkeypress'=>"mascara(this, data)" ));  

echo $this->Form->input('local_despesa', array('label'=>'Local da despesa', 'maxlength'=>'15'));  
echo $this->Form->input('fk_id_tipo', array('label'=>'Forma de pagamento:', 'type'=>'select', 'options'=>array('transacional'=>'Transacional', 'em espécie'=>'Em espécie')));  

//id do usuário para foreign key na despesa  
echo $this->Form->input('fk_id_user', array('value'=>$this->Session->read('Auth.User.id'), 'type'=>'hidden'));  

echo "<p>";  
echo $this->Form->submit('Inserir despesa');  
echo $this->Form->button('Limpar', array('type'=>'reset'));  
echo $this->Form->end();
```

Como eu faço um formulário numa outra *view* que passe no *model* e no *controler* de despesa? Ou seja, na *view* `/relatorio/buscar.cpp`, quando submetido, passaria no *model* `Despesa` para usar os *callbacks* `afterFind` e retornar o resultado para `/relatorio/exibir.cpp`.

Alguém pode me ajudar?

Comment: Poderia colocar o código do `controller`  da despesa e receita e forma que chama elas na model?